# how to send an email alert with the recipient email being included in a field on the custom object?

Tags: email, workflow, alert

I want to create an email alert every time a new item is created from a custom object. This custom object is called orders and contains a field called email where the customer email is included. For each order, the customer email changes. So, every time a new item is created from Orders (a new order is created), I want the specific customer of that order to receive an email. I don't know how to specify that the recipient from my workflow rule is included in the field (email) from the custom object. I would really appreciate any help!!

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the email field on the Order object is of type *email* you should be able to specify its content as the recipient by changing the *Recipient Type* to *Email Field* on the *Email Alert Edit* screen and then selecting the field from the *Available Recipients* box.

Comment: Hi! Okay you are right! The problem is that my Email field in Order is a lookup field from another object (Contact object). So when I select email field, there are no fields. Is there a way to add as a recipient this lookup field (it is an email field in the Contact object). THANK YOU!

Comment: In that case, you need to use a visual workflow or trigger to populate an Email-type field on create or change of the Contact's email field, and then run the email alert off of that field.

Comment: The workflow that I created has a Rule Criteria = True when a Order record is created or edited. And it is in that workflow that I wanted to include the email alert that sends an email to the email lookup field in Order. If a create the workflow you say, how would it that the email alert is set when a new order record is created? Maybe I should add a trigger on the workflow I created (¿?). Could you send me a screenshot of how you would create a trigger in my workflow?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with "  use a visual workflow or trigger to populate an Email-type field on create or change of the Contact's email field".. thank you for your help again, i really appreciate as I am quite new with salesforce